# How do I close a tkinter window automatically, after using a button to export a file

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I use the following python code to produce a popup window with a button that the user presses to export my Raw_dataframe to a csv.   What I want, is for the popup window to automatically close, once the user presses the button and finishes naming and exporting the csv.  Currently, the popup just stays open.

Here is the functioning code:

```
    root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'lightsteelblue2', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

def exportCSV ():
    global df

    export_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.csv')
    Raw_dataframe.to_csv (export_file_path, index = None, header=True)


saveAsButton_CSV = tk.Button(text='Export Raw Dataframe to CSV', command=exportCSV, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=saveAsButton_CSV)

root.mainloop()
```

The key is that I don't want to create another button to close the popup (which seems to be the usual answer in other questions.)  I want the popup to close automatically.

I've tried adding the following code

```
def quit(self):
self.destroy()
exit()
```

as suggested in other posts, but I can't seem to call it correctly.
I've also tried adding `root.destroy()` after my `canvas1.create_window`  command, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Call `root.destroy()` at the end of `exportCSV()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `exportCSV()` to:

```
def exportCSV ():
    global df

    export_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.csv')
    Raw_dataframe.to_csv (export_file_path, index = None, header=True)

    root.destroy() #!make sure it is called INSIDE the function
```